# Jenkins (cloudbees): remotely trigger build (e.g.via instant message) w/o creating user account in Cloudbees

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

We're using Jenkins (and precisely Cloudbees) for couple years. Well, it works.

Not I have new use case when I would like to allow trigger build remotely (w/o user account in Cloudbees).

Looks like it's impossible (standard token trigger mechanism requires an account in Cloudbees).

The only one way that I see it to set-up instant message integration (e.g. Jabber) and trigger builds in chat. It's nice solution that I would like to have, but ... it doesn't work for me. No errors and no messages (I tried different jabber servers).

Because I have only one such weird user I don't want to install special software (like Jabber/IRC server) and wanna use existing (like Gtalk or similar).

Any thoughts will be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> standard token trigger mechanism requires an account in Cloudbees

You can use the [Build Token Root plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Token+Root+Plugin) to bypass authentication long enough to check the token.

In the long term it would be desirable for Jenkins to let users create non-user principals that would have their own API tokens and SSH keys (but no UI login) and a restricted subset of permissions, so you could freely create a one-off principal for a specific purpose such as triggering builds. The infrastructure for such a feature does not exist today, however.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. 404 Tried in different ways. Did you have relevant experience with Cloudbees? I guess they can broken this plugin somehow.

Comment: I suspect that folder plugin can break this one. I.e. my URL is https://URL/job/trunk/job/Trunk%20auto/build not job/NAME/build as described on a plugin page.

Comment: Found a way how to trigger: https://URL/buildByToken/build?job=trunk/Trunk%20auto\&token=token\&cause=Cause+Text Please pay attention to \&

Comment: Right, jobs in folders are supported with slash syntax, and if you are entering a URL from a Unix shell you will need to escape any metacharacters such as `&` using backslashes or quotes.